# CUDA - specifiying <<<x,y>>> for a for loop

Tags: cuda

Hey,
I have two arrays of size 2000. I want to write a kernel to copy one array to the other. The array represents 1000 particles. index 0-999 will contain an x value and 1000-1999 the y value for their position.

I need a for loop to copy up to `N` particles from 1 array to the other. eg

```
    int halfway = 1000;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
         array1[i] = array2[i];
         array1[halfway + i] = array[halfway + i];
    }
```

Due to the number of N always being less than 2000, can I just create 2000 threads? or do I have to create several blocks.

I was thinking about doing this inside a kernel:

```
  int tid = threadIdx.x;

  if (tid >= N) return;

  array1[tid] = array2[tid];
  array1[halfway + tid] = array2[halfway + tid];
```

and calling it as follows:

```
  kernel<<<1,2000>>>(...);
```

Would this work? will it be fast? or will I be better off splitting the problem into blocks. I'm not sure how to do this, perhaps: (is this correct?)

```
  int tid = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

  if (tid >= N) return;

  array1[tid] = array2[tid];
  array1[halfway + tid] = array2[halfway + tid];

  kernel<<<4,256>>>(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

*Would this work?*

Have you actually tried it?

It will fail to launch, because you are allowed to have 512 threads maximum (value may vary on different architectures, mine is one of GTX 200-series). You will either need more blocks or have fewer threads and a for-loop inside with `blockDim.x` increment.

Your multi-block solution should work as well.

*Other approach*

If this is the only purpose of the kernel, you might as well try using `cudaMemcpy` with `cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice` as the last parameter.

Comment: I'm trying stuff out right now, it just takes close to 10 minutes for my program to run. Ah of course, I think `cudaMemcpy` would suffice here. Are you saying my multi-block solution will work as it is, or that I need a for loop with `blockDim.x` increment? is 4 a sensible choice for number of blocks? Cheers

Comment: I would also add that you need a good amount of computation to make using the GPU worthwile because of how slow it is to move data between host and device. In this case I would be surprised if the kernel is faster than a simple for loop on the CPU.
What would make it worthwhile is if you're doing other computations with those device memory particle arrays, which I hope is the case :)

Comment: @user660414 You'll need to loop over to support arrays bigger than 4 * 256.

Comment: "it just takes close to 10 minutes for my program to run" - what are you doing? Copying 2K data device<->device + launching a kernel takes less than a millisecond!

Comment: @tugudum I think I meant to do <<<8,256>>> which would give me enough threads to hold the array of size 2000. So no changes requried?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to answer questions about configurations is to test them. To do this, write your kernels so that they work regardless of the configuration. Often, I will assume that I will launch enough threads, which makes the kernel easier to write. Then, I will do something like this:

```
threads_per_block = 512;

num_blocks = SIZE_ARRAY/threads_per_block;
if(num_blocks*threads_per_block<SIZE_ARRAY)
    num_blocks++;

my_kernel <<< num_blocks, threads_per_block >>> ( ... );
```

(except, of course, threads_per_block might be a define, or a command line argument, or iterated to test many configurations)

Answer (score 0):

Is better to use more than one block for any kernel.

It Seems to me that you are simply copying from one array to another as a sequence of values with an offset.
If this is the case you can simply use the **cudaMemcpy** API call and specify
**cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice**

```
cudaMemcpy(array1+halfway,array1,1000,cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
```

The API will figure out the best partition of block / threads.

Comment: Because of the scheduling mechanism of the device. Each GPU has more than one SM and each block can be run on only one SM. If you have more than one block, each can be ran on a different SM, fully utilizing its hardware